# Implementing Java's getResponseCode() in C?

Tags: java, c, winsock, porting

If it's any help, there is also a similar class in C#'s WebRequest. Although I do not want it in java or .NET, i am wondering how to implement this in native C/C++ code (for windows).

for reference:

```
try {

URL url=new URL("http://google.ca");
HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.connect();
int code = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(code);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
System.err.println("Error reading URL.");
}
```

prints out:

```
200
```

meaning "OK"

I understand I probably need to use sockets and send a User-Agent string, but I haven't a clue where to begin. Whenever I learn a new language the first thing I like to do is try porting my code to it, but this one has stumped me.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no HTTP support in standard C library.

So you have two options - use 3rd-party HTTP library, such ar [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), or handle HTTP yourself:

- open socket
- resolve hostname
- connect to server
- build HTTP request
- send request to server
- receive HTTP response
- parse response and get response code from it.